Right way to inject dependencies in NestJS
I'm new to NestJS and also unfamiliar with DI. I'm building a simple API with NestJS. Everything is fine when each module have only 1 DB connect dependency. But when I inject a service to another service . Like this
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private prismaService: PrismaService,
    private cartService: CartService
  ) {}

with CartService like this
export class CartService {
  constructor(
    private prismaService: PrismaService,
    productService: ProductService
  ) {}

and now I have to provide all product dependencies in UserModule
@Module({
  providers: [UserService, PrismaService, JwtService, CartService, ...ProductDependencies],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
})

Now I'm having only 7-8 modules but in the long run it can be a mess. I think.
Is this ok or am I missing something?
Thanks for all your help

Check out the Nest JS documentation: Global Modules

If you have to import the same set of modules everywhere, it can get tedious. Unlike in Nest, Angularproviders are registered in the global scope. Once defined, they're available everywhere. Nest, however, encapsulates providers inside the module scope. You aren't able to use a module's providers elsewhere without first importing the encapsulating module.

When you want to provide a set of providers which should be available everywhere out-of-the-box (e.g., helpers, database connections, etc.), make the module global with the @Global() decorator.
So, if you don't want to inject the same dependencies many times, global modules can help you
